# Select HTML elements with jQuery by using logical OR in the selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

At the moment I have this HTML structure:

```
...
<div data-is_array="t" data-simpletype="int">
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div data-is_array="t" data-simpletype="char">
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div data-is_array="t" data-simpletype="text">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div data-is_array="t" data-simpletype="real">
    <input type="text">
</div>
...
```

And this CoffeeScript using jQuery:

```
$('*[data-is_array="t"][data-simpletype="int"] :input').each ->
    simpleCopy($(this))
$('*[data-is_array="t"][data-simpletype="char"] :input').each ->
    simpleCopy($(this))
$('*[data-is_array="t"][data-simpletype="text"] textarea').each ->
    simpleCopy($(this))
$('*[data-is_array="t"][data-simpletype="real"] :input').each ->
    simpleCopy($(this))
```

In the HTML there are other inputs wrapped in div's with other data. What I want is to call `simpleCopy` on all inputs that have `data-is_array="t"` and `data-simpletype` is `int`, `char`, `text` or `real`.

My current solution works but is not realy nice. Is there a way to get all these elements with sth. like a logical OR selector to do this in one like:

```
$('*[data-is_array="t"][data-simpletype="int||char||text||real"] :input||textarea').each ->
    simpleCopy($(this))
```

I know there is a [regex filter](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/), but I don't want to use this because this is realy slow when I test this under Chrome. Is there a better jQuery method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a mix of multiple selector and find/filter will do

```
$('[data-is_array="t"]').filter('[data-simpletype="int"], [data-simpletype="char"], [data-simpletype="text"], [data-simpletype="real"]').find(':input').each ->
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nzbPt/)

Comment: @tbraun89 check the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You're complicating it too much.

```
<div id="foo">
  <div data-is_array="t" data-simpletype="int">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div data-is_array="t" data-simpletype="char">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div data-is_array="t" data-simpletype="text">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
  <div data-is_array="t" data-simpletype="real">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Wrap it all with a div

```
$(' #foo input, #foo textarea ').each(function() {
  your stuff ()...
});
```

You're good. Good programmers are lazy programmers.

Comment: The problem is there are more elements that have `data-is_array="f"` or other values at `data-simpletype` and these should not be selected. And I can't add a div around all elements that match because they are generated dynamically.